# button to reset individual file input value with name "file[]" (array)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a remove button to clear the value for a `<input type="file">`. The problem I have is that I don't know how can I make each button point to their respective `<input>`.

I'm using the JQuery plugin ezdz to upload and create previews of the images and I can easily add the buttons to each input with the `$ezdz` predefined var:

```
$ezdz.parent('div').find('div.arrow_box').html('<p><a href="#" onClick="window.resetMethod($(this.form[\'file[]\']));return false;">Quitar imagen</a></p>');
$ezdz.parent('div').find('div.arrow_box').removeClass('hide');
```

I need to create a function to reset the file input:

```
window.resetMethod = 
function (e) {
      $(this).parent('div').find('input').get(0).reset();
}
```

But the problem is in the button...

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.resetMethod($(this.form[\'file[]\']));return false;">Quitar imagen</a>
```

This is the html code:

```
<div class="first">
    <!-- ezdz creates the following div and it'll be the container for the img -->
    <div>Drop a file</div> <!-- This div is $ezdz -->
    <input type="file" name="file[]" accept="image/jpeg" /><div class="arrow_box hide"></div>
</div>
```

Any idea to make this working?

EDIT: Sorry I didn't realized that function will reset the entire form. I need to reset the input above the button.

I'm getting the following error in console:

```
TypeError: $(...).parent(...).find(...).get(...) is undefined
```

Comment: You would get a lot better answers if you supplied people with more information about what your problem is, what causes it and what errors occur. From looking briefly I will venture a guess that the way you are adding the button is not binding the click listener to the window.

Comment: Yes sorry, but just binding the click listener to the window won't bind each button with their respective input. I'm not too skilled in jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.form[...]` in the `onClick`handler will fail. I suppose that your console will display an error. At the moment of the call *this* corresponds to the anchor element (`a`), and that element has no *form* property.

So replace:

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.resetMethod($(this.form[\'file[]\']));return false;">Quitar imagen</a>
```

By:

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.resetMethod($(this));return false;">Quitar imagen</a>
```

The function `resetMethod` does not require you to pass the *form* object. As long as the element is placed in the intended form, you can pass it (as jQuery object) to the function, and it will find that form, and reset it.

There seems to be a problem too with the `resetMethod` function, because of the wrapping it does. I would suggest skipping that part, and just use an `if`, like this:

```
window.resetMethod = function (elem) {
    var frm = elem.closest('form');
    if (frm.length) {
        frm.get(0).reset();
    }
    return false; // cancel default
}
```

Because of the `return false`, you can simplify the `onclick` part to:

```
<a href="#" onClick="return resetMethod($(this));">Quitar imagen</a>
```

You also do not need to use the `window` prefix.

Note that the function will also reset any other inputs you might have in the same form.

If you just want to reset the file-upload input, then use this variant of the function:

```
window.resetMethod = function (elem) {
      frm = elem.closest('form');
      console.log(frm);
      if (frm.length) {
          upload = frm.find('input[type=file]');
          console.log(upload);
          if (upload.length) {
              // clear file-upload by
              // re-injecting the html for it in the dom:
              upload.replaceWith($("<p>").append(upload.clone()).html());
          }
      }
      return false; // cancel default
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry if I provided poor information. Yes, I'm getting that error in console. I won't be in a hurry again when searching for scripts. I just now figured out (and thanks to you) that function will reset the entire form... What I'm looking for is to reset only the input type file (not all of them), just the one above the button.

Comment: I edited. I'm looking the function to do something like this `$(this).parent('div').find('input').get(0).reset();` is this possible? Or am I trying it the wrong way?

Comment: I added a version of the function that only resets the file upload input.

Comment: `reset()` on individual file-upload input does not work. You'll have to recreate the node in the document, which the code I suggested in my answer does.

Comment: Can't I just replace the input with a new one? Instead all of them?

Comment: That is what it does. Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1bL6ua0o/), which uses the above code on two forms with each an file-upload, and a link to clear it. The clearing only affects the current form's upload input.

Comment: I meant with only 1 form. But I think I can take it form here, thanks!